# Is it possible to make a sim and a tranciever send text messages to another sim ( with a tranciever )automatically?

Tags: java, c

Is it possible to make a sim and a transceiver send text messages to another sim ( with a transceiver )automatically?

(I'm not going to have a full fledged mobile ...I'm just going to use a microcontroller, transceiver and a sim)

Comment: I am sure its possible, but I don't see why you wouldn't just use an existing solution to this as it would be much, much cheaper to develop.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a microprocessor like this which supports sending text messages already, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapdragon_%28system_on_chip%29 , http://www.qualcomm.eu/uk/Snapdragon This is used in many popular smart phones.

Given these companies spend millions developing these solutions, even companies like Sony, Samsung and HTC use it (rather than develop their own) and you can buy the chips for a few dollars, it would make more sense to use something like this rather than develop your own IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I don't need any other capabilities other than sending messages regarding location data from my device to a central receiver periodically. These chips generally tend to be an overkill. So is there any other workaround?

Comment: Sure, you can develop it yourself.  The problem is that over kill or not, it could cost you millions, if not hundreds of millions, to do it yourself or it could cost you hundreds for a solution which does more than what you need.